# Rails: Validate with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date

I am using Rails 3.0.3 where I have quite an extensive validation process.

I want to make a validation where I check if a certain variable is a proper date

Basically this is what I want to do is:

```
def validate_date(this_date)?

    begin
       Date.parse(this_date)
    rescue
      proper_date = false
    else
          proper_date = true
    end
end
```

and call this method in my model using:

```
attr_accessor :given_date    
validate_date(given_date)
```

but also at another place in my validation file using for example:

```
attr_accessor :another_date
validate_date(another_date)
```

or something similar...

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is something similar to nkm's answer:

```
validates :name,
  presence => true # or other standard validations
validate :valid_my_date_variable

def valid_my_date_variable
  if my_date_variable.present?
    errors[:my_date_variable] << "is not valid" unless valid_date(my_date_variable)
  end
end

def validate_date(this_date)?
  begin
    Date.parse(this_date)
  rescue
    proper_date = false
  else
    proper_date = true
  end
end
```

Or you can create validator for your date and use it as you use standard validators.

Refer to [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) on how to create custom validator if you prefer keep your models cleaner.

Comment: Thanks. There were some minor errors in your code but I could fix it and this method works!

Answer (score 3):

you want to add errors instead of returning false, so instead you want to use:

```
errors.add(:date, "is invalid")
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually already did that. It doesn't really solve the core of my question though. How I should call this function using an argument.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that you should not do that in the first place. The validations occur against the attributes of the model, not against any input arguments to the validation methods. 
Do the following:

```
def validate_date

  begin
     Date.parse(this_date)
  rescue
     errors[:date_attribute] << 'is invalid date'
  end
end
```

This code above assumes that you have an attribute `date_attribute` in your `Model`. Change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but due to the setup of my application I have all my validations in one file (it's necessary) and I need to use input arguments. So this will not work...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this_date is the attribute(column_name) we need to validate, we can do the following,

```
validate :validate_date

  def validate_date
    begin
       Date.parse(this_date)
    rescue
       errors.add(:this_date, "is not valid")
    end
  end
```

Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. That will make the presence of name be validated IN CASE the date is validated. If validate date returns false it will just not validate name. It will not affect whether or not an error will be published (unless perhaps used in conjunction with the answer from Niclas). Alos, the calling of the method using :validate_date(this_date)? does not seem to work. I get this error:syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end
...=> true, :if => :validate_date(given_date)?